# Time complexity for loop with limit n*n

Tags: time-complexity

What is the time complexity for the following loop?

```
for(int i=0;i<(n*n);i++)
   System.out.println("Hello");
```

Is it O(n) or O(n^2)? And why?

Answer (score 3):

`O(n^2)` since the number of iterations is strictly higher than `n`, but is bounded from above by `n^2`.